# Get the latest order_date after aggregation my rows

Tags: sql, mariadb-10.3

I have 2 tables:

- `Customers` table (which has a `customer_id` column)
- `Orders` table (which has `customer_id` and `order_date` columns)

Is there a way to fetch all orders count for each customer with the latest order date in a single query ordered by the orders count, **without using correlated sub-query**?

I already have this:

```
SELECT C.customer_id, O.order_date, COUNT(O.order_id) AS orders_count 
FROM customers AS C
LEFT JOIN orders AS O ON O.customer_id = C.customer_id
GROUP BY C.customer_id
ORDER BY COUNT(O.order_id) DESC, O.order_date DESC
```

However, I only get the date of the first order the customer made.

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: Sorry it's `10.3.16-MariaDB`

Comment: Hardly seems worth mentioning, but anyway... see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `MAX()` aggregation function:

```
SELECT C.customer_id, MAX(O.order_date), COUNT(O.order_id) AS orders_count 
FROM customers C LEFT JOIN
     orders O
     ON O.customer_id = C.customer_id
GROUP BY C.customer_id
ORDER BY COUNT(O.order_id) DESC, MAX(O.order_date) DESC
```

Comment: ops! How on earth did I forget the `MAX()`! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if mysql 8.0+ version and maria db from 10.2 allow row_number() which will solve your problem

```
select * from (SELECT C.customer_id, O.order_date, COUNT(O.order_id) AS orders_count,
 row_number() over(partition  by  C.customer_id order by O.order_date DESC) rn
FROM customers AS C 
LEFT JOIN orders AS O ON O.customer_id = C.customer_id
 group by  C.customer_id, O.order_date
) a where a.rn=1
```

Comment: I'm getting the same number for `orders_count`